# Flutter AppBar Leading Text

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-layout, appbar

I want to make in my AppBar leading: Icon(Icons.settings) to ==>  Text('Settings'),

When I make just   `leading: Text('Cancel', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),`

[image]

---

and need to be like this down

[image]

basically I want to make to leading be Text not icon, is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resize leading widget in flutter AppBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082857/resize-leading-widget-in-flutter-appbar)

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52082857/12806961

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally you can put in the `leading` param of `AppBar` constructor any widget you want to.
If you want to swap `Icon(Icons.settings)` for `Text('Settings')` just do so!
If 'Settings' text has broken into two parts adjust it by setting proper value of `leadingWidth`.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: new ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
            accentColor: Colors.blue,
            textTheme: TextTheme(title: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
          leadingWidth: 75, //TODO Adjust leading container width
          leading: Center(
              child: Text(
            'Settings',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          )),
        )));
  }
}
```

I added `Center` widget and `TextStyle` for better experience.
[image]

Comment: For some reason still same, I'm able to make text, but text not showing in one line, looks like showing in column   

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6aOU.jpg

like this.  :/

Comment: Use leadingWidth attribute. I updated my response.

Comment: Thank you very much,  with adding  "leadingWidth: 75" this now is perfect..

Comment: Thanks this worked. I used the leadingWidth attribute